# Отправка сообщений в конкретное время и день недели

Tags: node.js, бот, discord, discord-api

Прошу помощи с кодом для отправки сообщений в заданный канал discord в определенное время в конкретный день недели. Например в каждую среду в 08:00 бот пишет "Доброе утро", а в 22:00 "Спокойной ночи". (Бот висит на хостинге и онлайн 24/7)
С отправкой сообщений по команде проблем нет, а вот как сделать это по времени не могу понять :(

Пример кода с отправкой по команде hi

````
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports.run = async (client,message,args) => {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Доброе утро!")
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setDescription('Доброе утро!')
    .setImage("---")
    .setURL("---")
    .setThumbnail("---")
    .setFooter('BOT 1.0', client.user.avatarURL)
 
    message.channel.send(embed);
    message.delete(100).catch();
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "hi"
};```
````

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cron

Answer (score 1):

Используйте пакет [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), имеющий подробную и понятную документацию.

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования node-cron

[image: пример]

День недели == 3 (среда)

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
 
cron.schedule('0 0 8 * * 3', () => {
  say('Доброе утро')
});
cron.schedule('0 0 22 * * 3', () => {
  say('Спокойной ночи')
});
```