# Автоматическая отправка сообщения в канал через время discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

Мне нужно чтобы бот автоматически отправлял сообщение, в канал к примеру через 5 минут. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Поставить `setTimeout()` на 5 минут

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1184863/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808514/178576)

Comment: Через 5 минут после чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  message.channel.send('Сообщение')
}, 300000)
```